# Vuejs rendering one item less

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new in Vuejs and I get an unexpected output in my app. What my app does is to search on YouTube API for channels, and then adding those channels in a list.

Then I like to render the list of the subscribed channels, but always I get one item less. Alway the last inserted item is missing from the rendered list, while the item exists in my data.

This is the rendered output:

[image]

If you see the right column, under the text box, has only one item rendered, while in my `Vue` console I have two items under the `channels_info` key:

[image]

Then if I try to append yet another one item in the list, the console will display 3 items while the HTML render will display 2, and so on.

My code is the following:

```
var setup = function () {
  app = new Vue(
    {
      el     : '#sml_app',
      data   : {
        channel_name         : '',
        errors               : [],
        channels_found       : {},
        no_channels_found    : true,
        next_page_token      : '',
        prev_page_token      : '',
        page_token           : '',
        subscriptions        : [],
        channels_info        : {},
        subscriptions_counter: 1
      },
      methods: {
        fetch_channel_info     : function ($channel_id) {
          var self = this;
          var base_api_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels';
          var query_params = {
            'part'      : 'snippet,contentDetails',
            'key'       : 'My-ApiKey',
            'maxResults': 1,
            'id'        : $channel_id
          };
          var get_params = '';

          for (var key in query_params) {

            if (get_params != '') {
              get_params += '&';
            }

            get_params += key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(query_params[key]);
          }

          get_params = '?' + get_params;

          axios.get(base_api_url + get_params).then(
            function (data) {
              data = 'data' in data ? data.data : {};

              if (
                typeof undefined !== typeof data.items &&
                typeof undefined !== typeof data.items[0] &&
                typeof undefined === typeof self.channels_info[$channel_id]
              ) {
                var snippet = data.items[0].snippet;
                var $key = self.subscriptions_counter + '-' + $channel_id;

                self.channels_info[$key] = snippet;
                self.subscriptions_counter += 1;
              }
            }
          ).catch(
            function () {
              self.errors.push(
                'No channel found matching this channel id.');
            }
          );
        },
        // ...
        append_to_subscriptions: function ($channel_id) {
          if (-1 === this.subscriptions.indexOf($channel_id)) {
            this.subscriptions.push($channel_id);

            this.fetch_channel_info($channel_id);

            // Todo-merianos: Create an AJAX request to set the options in
            // database
          }
        }
      }
    }
  );
};
```

While my HTML side is like that:

```
<div class="subscription" v-for="subscription in channels_info">
    <span v-text="subscription.title"></span>
</div>
```

Do you see anything in wrong ? I don't understand why I have that strange output :/

Any sugestion please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're appending a new property to an object. I recommend reading [this relevant section of the Vue.js documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats) regarding object change detection caveats. Specifically, you can use `Vue.set(object, key, value)` to ensure that your new object key is detected and becomes reactive.

So, instead of `self.channels_info[$key] = snippet;` you might instead do something like `Vue.set(this.channels_info, $key, snippet);`.

Definitely read through some more of the documentation. I'm certain that you'll find a lot of value in the rest of the information on this topic.

Comment: thank you for your reply. That solved my issue :). I will mark your answer as the one that solved my issue in a few seconds as I have to wait for it ;) :)